# R - finding the top 10 correlation values within dataset

Tags: r, data-science, correlation, analysis

I have a question regarding my data analysis. Specifically, I have calculated about 100 correlations and would like to see the top 10 correlation values from these 100 calculated correlations. Unfortunately, I'm a bit stuck right now and can't get any further. Can you help me how to output these top 10 correlation values automatically without checking them manually one by one?

The correlation values are calculated like this:

```
  my_correlation_1 <- function(ticker_subset, data) {
  cor(subset(data, TickerSymbol == ticker_subset, c(Sales, Stockprice_quarterly)))
}

mycor1 <- lapply(unique(dat$TickerSymbol), my_correlation_1, data = dat)
names(mycor1) <- unique(dat$TickerSymbol)
```

The correlation calculations provide results like this:

```
# $AMD
#                           Sales Stockprice_quarterly
# Sales                 1.0000000           -0.2261417
# Stockprice_quarterly -0.2261417            1.0000000
# 
# $AAPL
#                          Sales Stockprice_quarterly
# Sales                1.0000000            0.6531391
# Stockprice_quarterly 0.6531391            1.0000000
# 
# $EBAY
#                          Sales Stockprice_quarterly
# Sales                1.0000000            0.2032839
# Stockprice_quarterly 0.2032839            1.0000000
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll demonstrate using data we have: `mtcars`.

```r
allcors <- lapply(unique(mtcars$cyl), function(z) cor(subset(mtcars, cyl == z, select = c(mpg, disp))))
allcors
# [[1]]
#        mpg  disp
# mpg  1.000 0.103
# disp 0.103 1.000
# [[2]]
#         mpg   disp
# mpg   1.000 -0.805
# disp -0.805  1.000
# [[3]]
#        mpg  disp
# mpg   1.00 -0.52
# disp -0.52  1.00
```

In reality, we only need one non-diagonal value of each of these. From that, we can `rank` the value and move from there.

```r
sapply(allcors, function(z) z[2,1])
# [1]  0.103 -0.805 -0.520
rank(sapply(allcors, function(z) z[2,1]))
# [1] 3 1 2
```

Indicating that the second value is the lowest ranked value in the bunch. This is using the real value; if you want the rank of the absolute value, use `abs(.)`:

```r
abs(sapply(allcors, function(z) z[2,1]))
# [1] 0.103 0.805 0.520
rank(abs(sapply(allcors, function(z) z[2,1])))
# [1] 1 3 2
```

From here, if you want the top 2 of these 3 (which would be the top 10 of your `n`), then we can use which:

```r
which(allranks <= 2)
# [1] 1 3
```

meaning that the first and third of the original categories (your `TickerSymbol`) are the lowest rank.

And tying it back to the original categories,

```r
unique(mtcars$cyl)[ which(allranks <= 2) ]
# [1] 6 8
```

(There are the *least-correlated* in a sense. Use `-rank(.)` for the *most-correlated*.)

---

Alternatives, starting from scratch with the data and not using `lapply`:

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(corr = cor(cbind(mpg, disp))[2,1]) %>%
  slice_max(abs(corr), n=2)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#     cyl   corr
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     4 -0.805
# 2     8 -0.520
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(corr = cor(cbind(mpg, disp))[2,1]), by = cyl
  ][ rank(-abs(corr)) <= 2, ]
#      cyl   corr
#    <num>  <num>
# 1:     4 -0.805
# 2:     8 -0.520
```

### base R

```r
do.call(rbind,
  by(mtcars, mtcars["cyl"],
     FUN = function(z) data.frame(cyl = z$cyl[1], corr = cor(z$mpg, z$disp))
  )
)
#   cyl   corr
# 4   4 -0.805
# 6   6  0.103
# 8   8 -0.520
```

(which you can then sort/filter like the rest).

Comment: Thank you very much, the code helped me a lot! I really appreciate your help! Thank you!